# changing browser dependent css style from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a css style like:

```
    button.gradient {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00 0%, #009900 50%, #00dd00);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00ff00), color-stop(0.50, #009900), to(#00dd00) );
    }
```

It is a green button with gradient background color. How can I change the background color from green to blue using javascript while keeping the gradient effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Firefox nor Chrome use the prefixed version any more, and haven't for quite some time.
Source: http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient

So make your life easier, just use the correct syntax:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0f0, #090, #0d0);
```

Then you can simply change the gradient as desired.